how to split ceedling test code in multiple test files linked together at build time
I have the following
test/test_foo.c
test/test_fii.c
test/test_faa.c

test/utility.c
test/utility.h

All those tests have some code in common that I have refactored into a utility.c file. I created also a header files that I've included in the individual test files.
The problem is that when I run the tests ceedling test:foo the symbols inside utility.c are undefined because the linker does not link the two object togethers.
Here is my yml conf
:paths:
  :test:
    - +:test/**
    - -:test/support
  :source:
    - ../../src/**
  :include:
    .. my dependency for mocking
  :support:
    - test/support
  :libraries: []

What special configuration my yaml needs to have to fix this problem?
I tried modyfying the yaml without sucess

Your utility.[ch] files should be in the test/support/ directory.
